# JPA (Hibernate) / QueryDSL left join with condition doesn't work

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I have two tables - `user` and `booking`. Each user may have many bookings (one-to-many relationship).

```
user:                          booking:

    id | name    |               id | country    | user_id | price   |
    -------------|               ------------------------------------|
     1 | Alice   |                1 | Italy      | 1       | 2000    |
     2 | Bob     |                2 | France     | 1       | 2500    |
                                  3 | Spain      | 1       | 3000    |
```

I want to select all users and all bookings where booking's price is greater than 2000 using `Query DSL`. If a user doesn't have any bookings or bookings don't match the condition I still want to select this user.

First, let's have a look at how it would look like using a simple SQL left join query:

```
SELECT u.*, b.* FROM user u LEFT JOIN booking b ON u.id = b.user_id AND b.price > 2000
```

The above query should provide the following result:

```
    id | name    | id    | country    | user_id | price   |
    -------------|----------------------------------------|
     1 | Alice   | 2     | France     | 1       | 2500    |
     1 | Alice   | 3     | Spain      | 1       | 3000    |
     2 | Bob     | null  | null       | null    | null    |
```

Now I want to do it using `JPA` with `Query DSL`

**JPA-related stuff:**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, fetch = EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Booking> bookings;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Booking {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Query DSL:**

```
public List<User> getUsersAndBookings() {
    QUser user = QUser.user;
    QBooking booking = QBooking.booking;

    JPAQuery<User> jpaQuery = new JPAQuery(entityManager);

    List<User> result = jpaQuery.from(user).leftJoin(user.bookings, booking).on(booking.price.gt(2000)).fetchJoin().fetch();

    return result;
}
```

In fact, this code is not working and I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters [select user from com.example.demo.entity.User user left join fetch user.bookings as booking with booking.price > ?1]
```

The problem is that the condition clause is specified in `on` method - `on(booking.price.gt(2000))`.

After some research I found that this condition should be specified in `where` method and should look like this:

```
List<User> result = jpaQuery.from(user).leftJoin(user.bookings, booking).where(booking.price.gt(2000)).fetchJoin().fetch();
```

This works, but not how I would expect it to work, since it doesn't return ALL users, it returns only one user (Alice), which has some bookings, matching the condition clause. Basically, it just filters the merged table (result table after left join operation) and that's not what I'm looking for.

I want to retrieve all users, and if there are no any bookings for a specific user, then just have `null` instead of booking list for this user.

Please help, been struggling for hours without any success.

---

Versions used:

- Spring Boot 2.0.2
- Spring Data JPA 2.0.7
- Hibernate 5.2.16.Final
- QueryDSL 4.1.4

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I have this same requirement - need to load the user in result list, even if all his booking not matching the criteria. There I prefer a User object with empty bookings list. The answer by @leopal does not do this.

Comment: Got it fixed. See my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69421978/5035525

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isNull` expression in where clause to get the rows that have null values.

Your query should be like this:

```
jpaQuery.from(user)
    .leftJoin(user.bookings, booking)
    .fetchJoin()
    .where(booking.price.gt(2000).or(booking.id.isNull())).fetch();
```

Hibernate produced query:

```
select
user0_.id as id1_1_0_,
bookings1_.id as id1_0_1_,
user0_.name as name2_1_0_,
bookings1_.country as country2_0_1_,
bookings1_.price as price3_0_1_,
bookings1_.user_id as user_id4_0_1_,
bookings1_.user_id as user_id4_0_0__,
bookings1_.id as id1_0_0__
from
user user0_
left outer join
booking bookings1_
on user0_.id=bookings1_.user_id
where
bookings1_.id is null
or bookings1_.price>?
```

Comment: Hi, @leopal. Thank you for your response, but it still doesn't work as left join supposed to work. Let's consider my example again. Suppose that I want to fetch all users and their bookings where the price is greater than 5000 (no bookings exist matching this condition). I expect to retrieve ALL users - Alice and Bob, but your code returns only Alice, since she's got no any bookings at all. I created this sql fiddle to show what I'd like to retrieve - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0a182/2. The main idea is that I always want to retrieve all rows from the left table which is - user.

Comment: Have you tried this? `jpaQuery.from(user).leftJoin(booking)   .on(user.id.eq(booking.user.id).and(booking.price.gt(5000))).fetchJoin().fetch();`
Let me know if it has the desired results to update my answer.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work. the result of this query is all users with all bookings (price condition is ignored). I see that hibernate has generated 3 different queries, **1st query**: `Hibernate: /* select user from User user  left join fetch Booking booking with user.id = booking.user.id and booking.price > ?1 */ select user0_.id as id1_11_, user0_.name as name2_11_ from user user0_  left outer join booking booking1_  on (user0_.id=booking1_.user_id and booking1_.price>?)`

Comment: **2nd query**:
`Hibernate: select bookings0_.user_id as user_id4_1_0_, bookings0_.id as id1_1_0_, bookings0_.id as id1_1_1_, bookings0_.name as name2_1_1_, bookings0_.price as price3_1_1_, bookings0_.user_id as user_id4_1_1_ from booking bookings0_  where bookings0_.user_id=?` and 
**3rd query**: `Hibernate: select bookings0_.user_id as user_id4_1_0_, bookings0_.id as id1_1_0_, bookings0_.id as id1_1_1_, bookings0_.name as name2_1_1_, bookings0_.price as price3_1_1_, bookings0_.user_id as user_id4_1_1_  from booking bookings0_  where bookings0_.user_id=?`

Comment: I guess the first query looks fine, but I don't understand why does it generate two more queries, maybe that's the problem

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd queries are performed cause you have requested `Eager` fetch type for the list of the user's bookings(User class). If you use fetch type `Lazy` then these queries will be executed only when you explicitly call `user.getBookings` method.

Comment: Well if I am not missing something, you want to get from the query a `List of User` and for each user when you call `user.getBookings()` you wait to get the filtered bookings for this user(e.x price>2000). I think thi is not feasible with jpa. In order to achieve your initial goal, in the query I would `select` both user,booking and store this result to a Tuple. Then you can use this tuple to create a list of Users with the booking contained in the tuple(it will contain the filtered bookings e.x price>2000).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do. Why is it not feasible with JPA? The query seems to be pretty trivial, I just can't understand why it is difficult to implement it in JPA. Saying Tuple, do you mean Query DSL's Tuple interface?

Comment: Yes I mean Query DSL's Tuple interface. Of course you can do it with java by filtering the user booking but I think it is not efficient. You can change your query to `select(user,booking)` and fetch a Tuple. After this each row of the tuple will contain a User and the respective Booking(the filtered one). Don't forget that there will be null bookings. As for the reason why it is not feasible by default check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306235/jpa-one-to-many-filtering)

Comment: @leopal In general, your suggestion would not give the save results. The ON condition works at the moment when the two records are actually joined, so if it joins A and B, then it can leave the B side NULL, even if the B was not actually NULL (existed, but filtered out). As for the WHERE condition, it filters only the result set, so in our case it would filter out the whole record, whith A and B already joined.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no JPA way for this. But I got it fixed in Hibernate way, using Filters `org.hibernate.annotations.Filter`.

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name = "anyName", parameters = {
    @ParamDef(name = "price", type = "integer")
})
public class User {    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, fetch = EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    @Filter(name = "anyName", condition = "price > :inputPrice")
    private List<Booking> bookings;
}
```

Before querying the db, you must enable this filter.

```
Session session = enityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.enableFilter("anyName").setParameter("inputPrice", 2000);

// fetch using hql or criteria; but don't use booking.price.gt(2000) or similar condition there

session.disableFilter("anyName");
```

Now the result will have a `User` even if all of his booking prices are below 2000 and `bookings` list will be empty as expected.

**NOTE**: The word `price` in `condition` should be exactly same as the db column name; not as the model property name.